# mySQL CAST and ASC / DESC

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, redirect

I have a mysql_query

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CAST(row AS DECIMAL)
```

and want to change the sort direction.
I tried *ASC* and *DESC* but both return exactly the same sort direction.

How do I resort it?

Thanks, greets

Julian

Answer (score 1):

That should work. Have you tried to display that, what your CAST(row AS DECIMAL) produces?

Paste example of data that you trying to sort. Maybe you have nulls there or numbers that cant fit into decimal type.

What version of mysql you are using? Maybe reason is this (from mysql help):

> The change of storage format also means that DECIMAL columns no longer
>   support the nonstandard extension that permitted values larger than
>   the range implied by the column definition.

Comment: I use a remote application with GUI, called _Sequel Pro_. `CAST(row AS DECIMAL)` produces the output I expect. And without `CAST(row AS DECIMAL)` I can reorder the output as I want. There are no NULLS. I use sample data to test the code: {"a_1", "a_2", "a_10", "b_1", "b_2", "b_10"} as values of _row_

Comment: And I want to order this data "_Alphabetically_" and numbers as numbers (so that a_2 is after a_1 and a_10 is after a_2)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do your casting in the SELECT, and ORDER BY that new column. Downside is of course you would get 1 extra column in your response, but if that extra column doesn't affect anything then all's well.

```
SELECT *, CAST(row AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS tempCol FROM table ORDER BY tempCol
```

Also, your DECIMAL should ideally specify its precision. =)

More details at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html

Comment: I can't believe it… This looks so good, but don't work too! Every time I invoke _CAST_ into my query, the DESC or ASC doesn't effect anything! I really don't know why…

Comment: try this:

    select *, cast(left(row, charindex('_')) as INT) from table order by cast(left(row, charindex('_')) as INT)

Comment: Ah, the 'row' column is of TEXT datatype? Perhaps its to do with the casting of that into a numeric format.

Comment: @jsamraj: Maybe. But how could I do sorting? The content is `{"a_1", "a_2", "a_10", "b_1", "b_2", "b_10"}` and when I sort it ASC or DESC it outputs: `{"a_1", "a_10", "a_2", "b_1", "b_10", "b_2"}` but thats wrong, because 2 should be after 1 and 10 after 2, so on.

Comment: Ah, @Kamil think charindex is only specific to MS SQL. MySQL's one is substring_index =)

Comment: @ypercube was on to it. But i think what you're looking for is some sort of 'natural sorting'. As far as I can recall, MySQL is not really suited for natural sorting. You could try sorting by Length first and then the usual sort on the string field, but that would only work in very specific cases, like the example you provided in your comment. =)

Comment: I replaced **charindex** with **substrin_index** but it still don't work.

Comment: given your requirements as seen in the comments on ypercube's answer, I do also think doing this sorting in your application might be a better option. MySQL won't be able to handle such complex sorting given an unrestricted input of the column values. =)

Comment: Okay, thanks, @jsamraj. I'll think if it. Have you an idea how I could handle such complex sorting in PHP? Thanks, though

Comment: If you load the rows into some sort of array, natsort <http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php> might save you some work. But that is still pretty primitive, if you need to sort complex strings with custom logic then that might not work well enough for you. =)

Answer (score 1):

If your `row` column has only one `_` character inside, with the part before being alphabetic and the part after being numeric, this will work:

```
SELECT 
      *
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(row, '_', 1) AS  FirstPart
    , CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(row, '_', -1) AS UNSIGNED) AS SecondPart
FROM 
      TableX
ORDER BY
      FirstPart
    , SecondPart
```

Comment: I would splitt the strings if the query would be static. But it has to be dynamic. I pass a column name and a direction (ASC or DESC) to a PHP Script that makes the query and pass the returned content back to the main page.

Comment: **AND** the _content_ of the cells could be whatever. It's user input.

Comment: What's stopping you from using this query with a PHP script producing dynamic queries?

Comment: Define "whatever". Can the content be `'abc_123'` and `'abc_1_2_3'` and `'abc.1.2.3'` and `'a._1.b1_23a'` (and possibly many other variants)?

Comment: SUBSTRING_INDEX - very cool function, never heard of it :) Thanks.

Comment: You'r right. The cell content could be `'a_2'`, `'hello world 123'` or whatever a user puts into.

Comment: So, what should be ordered first? `hello 12 world 123` or `hello 123 world 12`?

Comment: 12 (twelve) is less than 123 (one hundred and three) so it should be `hello 12, hello 123`

Comment: And what about `'hello 23,4 world 12'`? Should that be considered as `23` or as `234`? And what about `'hello 3_4_6'`, etc... The options are incredibly complicated. You should write either a UDF or deal with such complex (and ill-defined in my opinion) ordering in your application code.

Comment: The code `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CAST(row AS DECIMAL)` outputs the perfect order. My only problem is that I cant invert the order with `ASC` and `DESC`

Comment: I bet it only outputs the perfect order by chance. Try adding a few more rows: `z_23`, `dd_23`, `aaa_1`, `bb_2` and test again.

Comment: Hum… You where right =( But how should I order the columns then?!