# How to fetch rows by desending order in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching the record from the table , i try my best to fetch by different method but not returning fine results .

I uses following code:

```
<?php 

$new_act_q=mysql_query("SELECT new_act FROM exel_file ORDER BY new_act DESC LIMIT 5");
while($new_act_f=mysql_fetch_assoc($new_act_q)){
echo $new_act_f['new_act']."<br>";
}

?>
```

But i am getting the wrong results , The result is showing as:

8

8

8

58

58

the returning result is not in the descending order.

Comment: what should be expected ?

Comment: What type is `new_act`? Probably a string, in which case it's as expected. 8 > 5

Comment: This is because the type of `new_act` is not integer

Answer (score 4):

If you want a numeric sorting order then new_act must be some numeric data type, or if the datatype is not some kind of numeric then cast it to a suitable numeric datatype in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast your row as UNSIGNED [INTEGER]:

```
SELECT new_act FROM exel_file ORDER BY CAST(new_act AS UNSIGNED) LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Check this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352279/mysql-cast-and-asc-desc